# Irreducible polynomials with coefficients $1$ over $GF(p)$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F=GF(p)$, the finite field with $p$ elements where $p$ is a prime. Is it always possible to find an irreducible polynomial of any degree with all nonzero coefficients are $1$?

Comment: For $p=3$, there is no polynomial of degree $2$ which you want.

Comment: What about $x^2+1$?

Comment: Here coefficient of x is 0. Do you allow this?

Comment: Oh, I see. I meant every nonzero coefficient of course. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $p=13$ and consider degree $2$ polynomials which you think:

$$x^2, x^2+x, x^2+x+1, x^2+1$$
First two are not irreducible.

For third, $3$ is a root.

For fourth $5$ is a root.

Comment: Good job! For the sake of completeness let me add that $x^2+x+1$ has roots in $\Bbb{F}_p, p>3,$ if and only if $p\equiv1\pmod3$. This is because $x^2+x+1$ is the third cyclotomic polynomial. Similarly $x^2+1$ is the fourth cyclotomic polynomial, and consequently it has zeros in $\Bbb{F}_p$ iff $p\equiv1\pmod4$.

Comment: @Jyrki: these are interesting observations; I had not known. Thanks for pointing it.